# Canon printer error 2, 140, 21

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer, lenovo-laptop, scanner

I have a canon Pixma MG2500 series 2570 printer that is 3 years old, and I wanted to test if it would work before scrapping it.
To day I installed the drivers from this [Canon official website](https://in.canon/en/support/0100668904)
everything worked fine(upto installation) but then I tried to scan something and then it displayed the following message:

[image]

I tried restarting the computer, reinstalling the drivers, and even a new usb cable.

I think what the problem is that maybe some windows process is using it in the background for my "convenience" and that's whats preventing the software from using.

Sometimes it even gives the "folder access denied" so I just allowed all the exe's related to canon to my files and folders.

note: it does not have ink, I just want to use it as a scanner.
I also downloaded the [Windows Scan app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/windows-scan/9wzdncrfj3pv?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) to see if it help, but no it didn't.

I would really appreciate it if anyone helped me. thanks.

For additional info: I'm on a Lenovo G50-80, 8 Gb RAM, Intel i3 5005u, 1Tb HDD, Windows 10 20H2

Comment: Your problem is that without ink the printer enters into an error state and refuses to scan. The [following procedure](https://www.instructables.com/Using-Canon-MP-198-Scanner-Without-Ink-or-Cartridg/) works for the Canon MP-198, see if it works for your model. There is also [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO6n8lyJtlg).

Comment: @harrymc this post is for printers with a display, and mine just has 3 led lights. . .
and the video is also about the mp-198 model. . .

Comment: If the firmware of both printers is similar, I wonder what would happen if you tried to follow the procedure blindly without display.

Comment: Many Pixma models also allow to reset the ink detection by pressing and holding “Stop” (button with orange circle and triangle) for 5 seconds.

Comment: @harrymc so sorry for the late reply actually your first comment is true without the ink the printer is refusing to work. 
also the button codes for the MG2570 differ for the MP-198. . . 
even holding the stop button doesn't work. . . I have decided to scrap it. . .
how do I cancel the bounty ?

Comment: You can't, your reputation has already been deducted. The only action left to you is to award the bounty. If you like I can put up an answer, or you may elect to let the bounty elapse.

Comment: can you like, put an elaborate answer ? so that it would be fair to me, you, and everyone else who sees this q/a . . .

Comment: I tried to make the answer as useful as possible, so it may help others in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Most Canon printers are designed to refuse to work without ink.
The printer then enters into an error state and refuses to scan.
The most common error code in this case is "2, 140, 21".
You need in such a case to work around the printer's firmware.

In the best case, the firmware permits the use to reset ink detection
by pressing and holding “Stop” (button with orange circle and triangle)
for 5 seconds. Many Pixma models allow that.

Another known workaround was found for the Canon MP-198 printer and
similar. It requires for the printer to have a digital display screen,
and you may need to redo it every time that you turn on the printer.
If this method doesn't work for the printer, then there is probably
no solution.

The [following procedure](https://www.instructables.com/Using-Canon-MP-198-Scanner-Without-Ink-or-Cartridg/) is described below, and there is also
[a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO6n8lyJtlg).

**Step 1: Remove All Cartridge**

Turn printer ON, lift upper body to access cartridge, remove cartridge by pushing it to the front (to you).

**Step 2: Enter 0 Mode**

Now we need to enter the mode where the display shows `0`.

- Turn printer OFF
- Disconnect USB cable
- Close front lid (where paper come out)
- Insert paper into paper tray (new sheet not crumpled).
- Press and HOLD "stop/reset"
- Press and HOLD the "ON" button
- Release "stop/reset" button
- Press and release "stop/reset" button two times
- Release "ON" button.
  Wait a moment, printer will enter into 0 mode, it will show `0` (zero)
  on its display.
- AFTER it shows `0`, turn OFF printer by pressing ON button
- PAPER will slightly coming/moving in.
  Go to the next step after PAPER is slightly coming/moving in.

**Step 3: Enter E3 Mode**

We enter E3 mode, where the display will blink "E" and "3" continuously.

- TURN ON printer
- PAPER will continue moving into the printer
- After half of the paper is inside, it will stop moving.
  The printer will display E3: blinking "E" and "3" continuously

**Step 4: Enter 1 Mode**

In 1 mode the printer will show `1` on the display.
This mode means the printer is ready to use (as scanner) without
ink cartridges.

- Open front lid (where paper come out after print)
- PAPER will continue moving and eventually coming out from front lid.
- Close front lid again.
- Finish, wait and it will go to 1 mode.

**Step 5: Start Scanning Without Any Ink or Cartridge**

Connect printer via USB to your PC to use it as a scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Try To Stop Printing Process
You will encounter 140, 21, Canon Printer Error Code 2 most likely when scanning the document over Canon printer. To solve this bug, you are required to give your system a simple command to stop printing the document. Just, follow the below-written instructions to quick fix the error code 2, 140, 21 from your Canon printer.

- First of all, go to the “Start” menu and choose Control Panel
- Under the Control Panel section, find the option “Devices & Printers” and
  hit on it Now, tap on your “Printer” button that is Canon printer At
  the end, click on “Stop Printing” button to stop the printing process